# Convert text box values in access query to mysql

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I am currently in the process of moving all my Access databases to a MySQL server. I have some pretty big queries I would like to convert into sql direct.

The only thing is that in those queries I am using the content of a textbox in my form :

```
IIf(IsNull([Formulaires]![DialogueMAJDossier]![FiltreTypeEntree]),[TypeDossier],[Formulaires]![DialogueMAJDossier]![FiltreTypeEntree])
```

(Excuse me for all the names being in french)

I know that when I convert it to MySQL syntax, it should give something like this :

```
IFNULL(`Formulaires`.`DialogueMAJDossier`.`FiltreTypeEntree`, `TypeDossier`)
```

But I have no idea how to account for the text box value in my query.

Any help will be gladly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Pass-Through queries cannot have parameters, so you'll have to use a workaround.

Option 1:
Save the SQL with "variables" in a template table, e.g. `SELECT foo, {FiltreTypeEntree} FROM bar`.
Then before executing the Pass-Through query, read the template SQL, `Replace()` the variable with the result of your `IIf` expression, and set the `.SQL` property of the query with the final string.

Option 2:
Create a "Variables" table in MySql. Fill its fields via code, and have your Pass-Through query join this table to get the variable values.

In a multi-user scenario, you'd have to introduce some kind of session management for Option 2, so I'd go with (1) in this case.